# substring datastage job parameter

Tags: datastage

I am executing Unix command in Datastage as follows:

`/unixScriptDir/remove_terms.ksh /SourceDir/ 20200225`

I have existing parameters in the DataStage, so my command will looks like this, except Date parameter in the different format than I need for this script – EnclRerunDt is in YYYY-MM-DD format, I need to substring it to the following format: YYYYMMDD. I am not sure how to do that.
I tried the following but DS does not understand: [#EnclRerunDt#,1,4]

```
#unixScriptDir#/remove_terms.ksh #SourceDir# [#EnclRerunDt#,1,4][# EnclRerunDt#,6,2][# EnclRerunDt#,9,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring function is in following format in DataStage

> field[start, length]

So try something like this

```
#EnclRerunDt#[1,4] : #EnclRerunDt#[6,2] : #EnclRerunDt#[9,2]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. At the end I created user variable and trimmed date parts into it, and than used this variable in the unix script.

Comment: Command '#EnclRerunDt#[1,4] : #EnclRerunDt#[6,2] : #EnclRerunDt#[9,2]' did not worked under command activities under parameters. The way I did it, I created user variable 'UserVariables' as follows: 'Trim(EnclRerunDt)[1,4]:Trim(EnclRerunDt)[6,2]:Trim(EnclRerunDt)[9,2]' and used this variable in the command activities parameter as follow: ' #UserVariables.New#'